# bash CSV last column

Tags: bash

I have csv in format like this

```
 John|Mayer   
 Bill|Potter
 ...
```

script is:

```
cat names.csv | while read line
 do
    name=$( echo $line | cut -d'|' -f1 )     # get the first name
    surname=$( echo $line | cut -d'|' -f2 )    # get the surname      

echo "$surname"
echo "Your name is: $name and surname is: $surname"
done
```

echo of surname is working and i get list (Mayer Potter...). 
But it is not works when i use it as variable in some other context (and surname is: $surname")

Comment: Please post your Input_file in code tags and please post your expected output too in code tags with all your conditions, thank you.

Comment: Are you saying that outside of the loop, the variables disappear?

Comment: Your script and mine have the same result. The both works. Describe better your problem, please.

Comment: Better to use it as: `while IFS='|' read -r fname lname; do declare -p fname lname; done < names.csv`

Comment: @anubhava, you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer.

You have few issues in your loop:

1. Unnecessary use of `cat` and a pipeline due to that which will fork a subshell
2. Unnecessary use of `cut` twice inside the loop when you can do same using `IFS`

You can use this loop:

```
while IFS='|' read -r fname lname; do
    declare -p fname lname
    # or do processing with $fname, $lname here
done < names.csv
```

Comment: script works with | and , but not working with ; as delimiter. If I export from excel i get ; delimiter. So i must resave csv file to work.

Comment: In that case just change `IFS='|'` to `IFS='|;'` so that it splits on `|` or `;`

Comment: seems that problem was that i needed to convert from dos 2 unix ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is because in bash commands arround pipe `|` are executed in a sub process,

so after `done` current shell environement is the same as before commands

see :

```
declare -p BASHPID  
declare -p BASHPID  >&2 | declare -p BASHPID >&2
```

this can be resolved using input redirection instead of `cat |`

```
while read line
do
...
done < names.csv
```

also it avoids spawning two processes and creating a pipe